# How to make a 3 frame walking animation in java

Tags: java, animation

I am working on a game in java, and when the player is walking sideways it looks really tacky. I was advised to use a three-frame animation, and I have been trying so many searches and I just cannot seem to figure it out.

**dir** is what I use to get which way the player is looking, 0 is forward.
**sprite** is to get the image, playerF, playerF_1, and playerF_2 are all for the forward character.
**walking** is a boolean for the animation to be going or not.
**anim** is short for animation.

```
if (dir == 0) {
    sprite = Sprite.playerF;
    if (walking) {
        if (anim % 40 > 20) {
            sprite = Sprite.playerF_1;
        } else {
            sprite = Sprite.playerF_2;
        }
    }
}
```

I thank you in advanced for helping me create a 3-frame animation.

Comment: How is this unclear? Question is fine, unreasonable hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in a third option in the if/elseif chain:

```
    if (walking) {
        if (anim % 40 >= 30) {
            sprite = Sprite.playerF_2;
        else if (anim % 40 >= 20) {
            sprite = Sprite.playerF_1;
        } else if (anim % 40 >= 10) {
            sprite = Sprite.playerF_2;
        } else {
            sprite = Sprite.playerF_3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the frames to go like 1.2.3.2.1.2.. but instead that code goes 1.2.3.1.2.3.. if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Shzylo Then add in a fourth that uses `Sprite.playerF_2` again. Same idea :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have done basically the same thing but I guess I did something wrong.

Comment: @Shzylo Don't forget to try debugging when you get stumped by something that ought to be simple.

Comment: Actually, what is going on is when I was first testing it, I didn't use the actual sprites. When I went to use the sprites I noticed that the order is 1.2.1.3.1.2.1.3.. or some weird order that doesn't go into it correctly. And when it uses frame 3, it will take longer to process.

Comment: Figured it out! What I did was I used a debug method and put Sysout in each of the if statements, it started from bottom-to-top so I just organized it to flip through them correctly! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it.

This method scales to as many directions(eg. including diagonals) and frames as you could possibly want without the need for hard coding a massive else if block.

Create an enum to hold your possible directions.

```
enum Direction{
    Forward,
    Backward,
    Left,
    Right       
};
```

Then create an `EnumMap` using a direction as the key and having a value of an array of Sprites

`EnumMap<Direction,Sprite[]> animations = null;`

Then add your frames for each animation to their respective directions

`animations.put(Direction.Forward,new Sprite[]{Sprite.Sprite.playerF,Sprite.playerF_1,Sprite.playerF_2});`

Now to do your draw update function all you have to do is

```
if(walking){
     sprite = animations.get(dir)[getFrame(anim)];
}
```

Now to handle the decision of what frame to use. Assuming `anim` is some sort of frame counter and you want to update less often than every frame.

For looping eg. 1,2,3,1,2,3,... animations:

```
int getFrame(int anim){
     return (anim / UPDATE_FREQUENCY) % FRAME_COUNT;
}
```

or for bouncing animations eg. 1,2,3,2,1,2,3,... keep a variable in your draw section to keep trace of what number frame was drawn and what direction it is currently going.

```
int getFrame(int anim, int frameNum, Boolean incrementDirection){
    int frame;
    if(anim % UPDATE_FREQUENCY == 0){
       if(Math.abs(frameNum) == FRAME_COUNT-1)
                 frameNum = 0-frameNum;
        frameNum ++;
    }
    return frameNum;
}
```

To implement this version the draw code would be changed to

```
int frame = 1;

if(walking){
     frame = getFrame(anim,frame);
     sprite = animations.get(dir)[Math.abs(frame)];
}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem of it saying that 'Sprite sprite' cannot handle 'Sprite', which is where I call to get my images, and it says that it needs to be a String.

Comment: Opps, just noticed I forgot to change String to Sprite in the EnumMap definition. I was using String for testing as I do not have the library containing Sprite.

Comment: @Sam use a tag in your comments to give shzylo a notification